# How to check if a function parameter is null

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know if a function passed by the constructor is null or not, but when I check it, it doesn't recognize the function as null, even though I didn't pass anything as a parameter.

This is my widget:

```dart
const CropImageWidget({
    this.navBack,
    super.key,
  });

final Function? navBack;
```

Here is where I check if `navBack` is `null` or not:

```dart
if (widget.navBack == null) {
   Navigator.pop(context);
}
widget.navBack!();
```

The problem is that `widget.navBack` is never `null`.

I need to check if a function is or isn't passed in the constructor to execute function or to just pop the screen.

Solution:
I thought the Navigator.pop(context) would return and not execute the code after it, however it executes the pop and then executes the function, which gives me the error. So, to make the code work I just did an If/else like this:

```dart
if (widget.navBack == null) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
} else {
    widget.navBack!();
}
```

Comment: what is your error ? how do you call your cropImageWidget ?

Comment: actually you can answer to your own question. do not put the answer in the question section. to help other people find the answer who has same issue later

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Posted the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the Navigator.pop(context) would return and not execute the code after it, however it executes the pop and then executes the function, which gives me the error. So, to make the code work I just did an If/else like this:

```dart
if (widget.navBack == null) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
} else {
    widget.navBack!();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
           final VoidCallback? navBack;

            onPressed: (){
              if(navBack == null){
             Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            }
```

Comment: This didn't work. I think I have found the solution. I thought the  Navigator.pop(context); would return and not execute the code after it, however it executes the pop and then executes the function, which gives me the error.

Comment: it works for me. I run the code before posting. it might be a problem with your linter.